# Can't import QtWebEngineWidgets in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

I'm currently developing a web browser in Python using Qt5. However, when I try to run it, I get the following:

```
ImportError: No module named QtWebEngineWidgets
```

What this error is referring to is one of the import statements in my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebView
```

If anyone could help me here, it'd be much appreciated.

-CodeExecution

Comment: 32 bits or 64 bits?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3, which has a 64-bit CPU, but a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: As far as I know raspberry does not support QtWebEngine, and therefore PyQt for raspberry either.

Comment: Actually, I've already got PyQt5 on the RPi3, but can't get QtWebEngineWidgets.

Comment: I'm telling you that QtWebEngine is not supported by RPi, so there is no such submodule in PyQt5 either. In conclusion you can use the submodules of PyQt5 but not the submodule of QtWebEngine

Comment: @eyllanesc The python-pyqt5.qtwebengine package is only available in Debian Sid repositories. Just added the Debian Sid mirror to my /etc/apt/sources.list, and ran sudo apt update. Then, I ran sudo apt install python-pyqt5.qtwebengine, and QtWebEngine is currently installing.

Comment: It only exists for amd64 and i386, not for ARM: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine

Comment: the installation that indicates is only an unpacked, it is not an installation properly compiled for ARM.

Comment: The Sid version (https://packages.debian.org/sid/python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine) is available for ARM.

Comment: interesting, have you solved your problem ?, I ask you because I see that you have published an answer

Comment: Yes, I had to add the Sid repositories, make apt trust those repositories, run sudo apt update, and then try to install it. It is installing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the package "python-pyqt5.qtwebengine" doesn't exist in the Raspbian (the OS I'm running on my RPi) repositories, but it does exist in the Debian Sid repositories. I had to add the Debian Sid mirror to my /etc/apt/sources.list, and then run the following commands to make my system "trust" the Debian repositories:

```
gpg -a --export 04EE7237B7D453EC | sudo apt-key add -
gpg -a --export 7638D0442B90D010 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then I did sudo apt update, and then sudo apt install python-pyqt5.qtwebengine. It's installing right now. After it has finished installing, I will remove the Debian Sid repositories.